# Page blank while username and password are not correct - login - PHP

Tags: php, html, cookies, authentication

I am trying to make a login system using only PHP (no MySQL or SQLite). But for some reason the code, which is supposed to show an error, while the details are incorrect shows a blank page. Works if they are correct. 
(This is just a prototype for testing. I am not going to make a "if/else" for each user)
My code:

```
<?php

if (isset($_POST['user']) && isset($_POST['pass'])) {
 if ($_POST['user'] == "jakeajames" && $_POST['pass'] == "test123") {
  setcookie("loggedin", "yes", time() + 60 * 60 * 3, "/");
   header("Location: home.php");
 }
elseif ($_POST['user'] != "jakeajames" && $_POST['pass'] != "test123" && isset($_COOKIE['failed3']))
{
  switch ($_COOKIE['failed3']) {
  case "1":
    setcookie("failed3", "2", time() + 60, "/");

echo '<html>
<head><title>Login</title></head>
<body>
<center>
<p style="color: red;"> 2 attempts remaining</p>
<form method="post">
Usename: <input type="text" placeholder="username" name="user"></input><br>
Password: <input type="password" placeholder="password" name="pass"></input><br>
<input type="submit"></input>
</form>
</body>
</html>';

  break;
  case "2":
 setcookie("failed3", "3", time() + 60, "/");
echo '<html>
<head><title>Login </title></head>
<body>
<center>
<p style="color: red;"> 1 attempt remaining</p>
<form method="post">
Usename: <input type="text" placeholder="username" name="user"></input><br>
Password: <input type="password" placeholder="password" name="pass"></input><br>
<input type="submit"></input>
</form>
</body>
</html>';
break;
case "3":
  echo "You need to wait 60 seconds till you can login again";
  break;
}


}
elseif ($_POST['user'] != "jakeajames" && $_POST['pass'] != "test123" && isset($_COOKIE['failed3'])) {
  setcookie("failed3", "1", time() + 60, "/");
}

}



if (!isset($_POST['user']) && !isset($_POST['pass'])) {
 echo '<html>
<head><title>Login</title></head>
<body>
<center>

<form method="post">
Usename: <input type="text" placeholder="username" name="user"></input><br>
Password: <input type="password" placeholder="password" name="pass"> </input><br>
<input type="submit"></input>
</form>
</body>
</html>';
}
?>
```

Comment: *blank page* means something is broken. Add these lines at the very top of your PHP script, `ini_set('display_errors', 1); error_reporting(E_ALL);` and see if it yields any error or not.

Comment: Well not. If it was an error it would be shown on the error log which I checked. Also this is the second time I try it from scratch and the same thing happens

Comment: its blank may because there is no else condition in your code. one condition where there will be nothing to show when either username or password correct

Comment: I hope this is strictly for academic purposes.

Comment: You should also add an `exit;` after header. Otherwise, your code may want to continue executing.

Comment: I know that. I tried putting both them wrong and it shows the blank page

Answer (score 1, accepted):

correct line number near 50, you are checking the same condition again

```
elseif ($_POST['user'] != "jakeajames" && $_POST['pass'] != "test123" && isset($_COOKIE['failed3'])) {
                                                                         ^add !here
     setcookie("failed3", "1", time() + 60, "/");
}
```

and correct one is

```
elseif ($_POST['user'] != "jakeajames" && $_POST['pass'] != "test123" && !isset($_COOKIE['failed3'])) {
    setcookie("failed3", "1", time() + 60, "/");
}
```

and output is

[image: after corrected]

Comment: Oh, how did I miss that!

Comment: some times it happens :)

Comment: Now I have another problem. How can I make it so it checks the cookie "failed3" at the load of the page and shows the errors ?